# Multi-client conferencing in Lync 2010 Client

Tags: lync-2010, lync-server-2010

Does Microsoft Lync 2010 Client support multi-client audio/video conferencing?

Answer (score 0):

If by Multi-Client conferencing, you mean more than 2 parties, then yes, this is supported - but you'll probably get a better answer for this kind of question on [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com)